# How do I register a trademark in the USA if I'm not in the USA and I'm not a US citizen?

Tags: trademark

I want to register a trademark. It's a word that I've been using for my website domain for a long time (over 3 years).

I just want to make myself feeling more safe so I want to register a trademark.

However, I'm not a US Citizen and I do have a lot of visitors from the US.

How can I get started? Thanks for any kind of tips. I even don't know what to search on Google.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know how to do it if you were a US citizen in the US? No? Then why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: Why do you want a US trademark if most of your business is from other countries? Surely you’d want trademarks in those countries?